# how to complete the following R plot?

Tags: r, plot

I use the following R plot commands to create a plot - I managed to find the "right" commands after quite many look-ups in Google - but it is still not perfect:

```
x = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4);

y = c(100,200,300,400);

z = c(81,82,83,87);

w = 150;

v = 85.5;

plot(x,y, type="l", lwd=4, xlab="threshold", ylab="seconds");

points(x, y, col="red", cex=2, pch=19);

abline(h=w, col="red", lwd=4);

par("usr");

par(usr = c(par("usr")[1:2], 80,90));

axis(4, lwd=4);

points(x, z, col="blue", cex=2, pch=19);

points(x, z, type="l", lwd=4);

abline(h=v, col="blue", lwd=4);
```

What I am looking for is a few things:

1. adding a text next to the right y axis. I saw somewhere someone suggested using mtext, but it is not working for me. Isn't there a way to have a label attached to the right y axis with the axis command? adding ylab or lab doesn't help.
2. I want the color of the text next to the y axis to be blue and red (so that it is clear, according to the dots in the graphs, which curve goes with which axis). Is that possible to color *only* the label of the y axis? (well, first I have to get a label for the right y axis!)
3. I want to make the lines of the left y axis (and the tick marks) as thick as they are in the right y axis. Same for the x axis. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you explain how `mtext` isn't working for you?  Something like `mtext("Your text", side = 4, col = "blue")` should work fine.

Comment: I think the reason you _think_ `mtext` isn't working is that you haven't adjusted the margins of the plot to make space for that text on the right (`par(mar = ...)`). Everything else can be easily done using `axis` and `mtext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
par("mar")
par(mar = c(par("mar")[1:3], 5.1))

plot(x,y, type="n", lwd=4, ylab="", xlab="threshold", xaxt="n",yaxt="n")

axis(1,lwd=4)
axis(2,lwd=4)

points(x, y, col="red", cex=2, pch=19)
abline(h=w, col="red", lwd=4)

par("usr")
par(usr = c(par("usr")[1:2], 80,90))

axis(4, lwd=4)
points(x, z, col="blue", cex=2, pch=19)
points(x, z, type="l", lwd=4)
abline(h=v, col="blue", lwd=4)

mtext("Your text", side = 4, col = "blue",line=3)
mtext("seconds", side = 2, col = "red",line=3)
```

[image]

Comment: this is almost perfect, thanks! (and I marked it as the correct answer) - but some questions: the upper line in the plot (border) is thin, can it be removed? also, the Y axes don't start at the same height, is there a way to control for that? last, is there a way to control the size and the boldness of the font of the axes and the labels?

Comment: see `?par` for all the graphical parameters. Specifying `bty="n"` in the `plot` statement will remove the outer box. Some other parameters in `?par` that might be useful to look at to answer your queries include `yaxs` / `xaxs` / `ylim` / `font` / `font.axis`